# Get reference to hovered element in jQuery UI Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, jquery-ui-tooltip

Basically, I'm attaching an `open` handler to my jQuery UI tooltip which performs some checks on the element that triggered the tooltip. What I've got so far:

```
$(document).tooltip({
  open: function(e, ui) {
    var el = e.toElement/* || e.relatedTarget*/;
    console.log(el.offsetWidth, el.scrollWidth);
    if (el.offsetWidth === el.scrollWidth) {
      ui.tooltip.hide();
    }
  }
});
```

The check above prevents the tooltip from appearing unless the element is overflowing horizontally, part of a fluid layout. It works nicely in Chrome as you can see in this [**jsBin**](http://jsbin.com/uxilag/16/edit).

However, in Firefox, `event.toElement` is `undefined`. From reading threads around SO, I've thought that `event.relatedTarget` would be a suitable substitute, but it is not. While `event.toElement` references the currently hovered item, the `event.relatedTarget` in  a `mouseover` references the element which the pointing device exited, which is the correct behavior as per [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MouseEvent-relatedTarget) (similar to Chrome's `event.fromTarget`).

I've also tried [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/), [`event.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) and the `this` reference but these point to `document` as it is the node which has the tooltip event handlers bound to. Going through the [Tooltip API](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/) page didn't help either.

I'm not sure whether I'm overlooking something extremely basic, or if I should try even less orthodox methods.

Is there a way to get a reference to the element that triggered the from inside the tooltip's `open` handler which works in Firefox? Or is there some magic jQuery UI Tooltip option/method that can attain this desired behavior in a simpler/similar way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness: The widget contains the property `tooltips`, an object that contains the ids of all open tooltips as key and the associated target element as value.

```
var widget = $(this).data("ui-tooltip");
var el = widget.tooltips[ui.tooltip[0].id][0];
```

It's clean because you have a direct reference to the element, but also a bit dirty because it's an implementation detail that might change.

That said, something like `ui.target` would indeed be nice.

Comment: Oh I was aware of the `tooltips` property, but failed to figure out the `.data("ui-tooltip")` part lol. Yeah this is a cleaner solution, thanks.

Comment: For the sake of performance and future reference, here's the updated bin with your code using the static `$.data` method: http://jsbin.com/uxilag/50/edit

Answer (score 7):

This is a rather hackish solution, but here goes the temporary fix which I just found. **edit:** after having finished the 1st cross-browser solution below, it is not so hackish at all. The **#1**, **#4** and **#2** solution listed below should be usable.

jQuery Event objects have a hidden `originalEvent` property, which in the question's case is a references a native `mouseover` event. Therefore `event.originalEvent.target` can be used for both Chrome and Firefox.

```
open: function(e, ui) {
  var el = e.originalEvent.target;
  if (el.offsetWidth === el.scrollWidth) {
    ui.tooltip.hide();
  }
}
```

[**Bin**](http://jsbin.com/uxilag/23/edit)

When old IE support is concerned, you will have to use [`event.srcElement`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljahrnvn.php) when [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.target) is not present.

```
var el = e.originalEvent.target || e.originalEvent.srcElement;
```

[**Bin**](http://jsbin.com/uxilag/22/edit)

---

### #1 Cross-browser solution

Finally, when there are nested elements inside of an element that triggers the tooltip, you will have to monkeypatch it by using the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method passing in the same filter as your tooltip's delegation selector ([`items` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-items), default to `[title]:not([disabled])` as of UI 1.10.2):

```
var el = $(e.originalEvent.target || e.originalEvent.srcElement).closest($(this).tooltip('option', 'items'))[0];
```

[**Bin**](http://jsbin.com/uxilag/25/edit)

This is basically what the Tooltip Widget does internally as shown [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.tooltip.js#L140-L143).

---

### #2 Alternative cross-browser solution

Alternative solution that doesn't require so many workarounds by using a simple DOM query:

```
var el = $('[aria-describedby="'+ui.tooltip[0].id+'"]')[0];
```

[**Bin**](http://jsbin.com/uxilag/28/edit)

---

#3 Internal methods abuse

This should not be used, but by overriding the internal `_open` method you get access to a `target` jQuery object which contains the event's target element passed as parameter to it. Problem is, then you don't have access to its `tooltip` widget not even through `.tooltip('widget')` as it is "not created" yet though already present in the DOM. You can work around it using the internal `_find` method which will perform a [DOM query by ID](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/e4a786e1a4fdd85b391711688bcb9790f38b5352/ui/jquery.ui.tooltip.js#L369-L372) and thus you can `hide` it right after the `show` animation would kick in, while its live cycle is not affected - it will be there and removed on `mouseleave` as usual, but will have `display:none` along all this cycle.

```
var bk_open = $.ui.tooltip.prototype._open;
$.ui.tooltip.prototype._open = function(event, target, content) {
  bk_open.apply(this, arguments);
  if (target[0].offsetWidth === target[0].scrollWidth) {
    this._find(target).hide();
  }
};

$(document).tooltip();
```

[**Bin**](http://jsbin.com/uxilag/35/edit)

That DOM query with `_find` is rather unnecessary, so we can also extend the internal `_tooltip` method which returns a jQuery object containing the `tooltip` element so we can use JS's lexical scope to save a reference to the tooltip element before our overridden `_open` executes:

```
var tooltipproto = $.ui.tooltip.prototype,
    bk_open = tooltipproto._open,
    bk_tooltip = tooltipproto._tooltip,
    $tooltip;
tooltipproto._open = function(event, target, content) {
  bk_open.apply(this, arguments);
  if (target[0].offsetWidth === target[0].scrollWidth) {
    $tooltip.hide();
  }
};
tooltipproto._tooltip = function(element) {
  return ($tooltip = bk_tooltip.apply(this, arguments));
};
$(document).tooltip();
```

[**Bin**](http://jsbin.com/uxilag/38/edit)

Of course, as the `_tooltip` internal methods receives the `target` as parameter and returns the `tooltip`, one could do the entire operation just overriding this method, but as the `tooltip` is `show`n after this method returns, this would require a `setTimeout(fn, 0)` possibly causing an undesirable flicker effect.

This is overly hackish, cumbersome and verbose for something so simple though.

---

### #4 Clean solution

"Clean" as in not using undocumented methods nor attributes nor prototype overriding nor DOM queries. Back to the first snippet, all we needed was a reference to the element that triggered the tooltip. This element is referenced by the `this` inside of the `content` function which is called prior to the `open` handler, thus we can use lexical scope to store that reference a level above:

```
var el;
$(document).tooltip({
  content: function() {
    el = this;
    return this.title;
  },
  open: function(e, ui) {
    if (el.offsetWidth === el.scrollWidth) {
      ui.tooltip.hide();
    }
  }
});
```

[**Bin**](http://jsbin.com/uxilag/43/edit)

Note that my custom `content` function in the snippet above removes jQuery's [default HTML tags stripping](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/e4a786e1a4fdd85b391711688bcb9790f38b5352/ui/jquery.ui.tooltip.js#L53) (because I like using HTML inside the tooltips), but this may be an issue if you're dynamically populating the title attribute with user-inputted data, so in case you want to keep the original `content` handler's functionality:

```
var el,
    bk_content = $.ui.tooltip.prototype.options.content;
$(document).tooltip({
  content: function() {
    el = this;
    return bk_content.apply(this, arguments);
  },
  open: function(e, ui) {
    if (el.offsetWidth === el.scrollWidth) {
      ui.tooltip.hide();
    }
  }
});
```

[**Bin**](http://jsbin.com/uxilag/44/edit)

---

I'll open a ticket on jQuery UI bugtracker requesting this feature to be implemented meanwhile. Here's it:

[Tooltip: Expose element which triggered the tooltip inside open/close handlers](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9239)